# Scrapy-Splash with Tor

Tags: scrapy, tor, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render, polipo

I have succeed to run Scrapy with Tor using this link: http://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents-part-1-mac/

But i couldn't run Splash with Tor.

In Scrapy-settings.py I directed to polipo for http_proxy(8123 is polipo port):

```
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
```

In polipo.config, I directed to tor(9150 is tor port):

```
socksParentProxy = localhost:9150

diskCacheRoot=""
```

Which works perfect for scrapy. In splash it doesn't work. But i have to say splash or docker to use polipo for http_proxy like in scrapy-settings.py. Docker should somehow use polipo, and polipo will direct to tor. How can i do that?

I run splash with:

```
sudo docker run -p 5023:5023 -p 8050:8050 -p 80511 scrapinghub/splash
```

and in etc/default/docker i tried docker should direct to polipo with this:

```
export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:8123'
Environment="http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8123"
```

But i couldn't succeed. What am i doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to

1. make Tor accessible from Splash Docker container;
2. tell Splash to use this Tor proxy.

For (2) you can use either Splash [proxy profiles](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#proxy-profiles) or set proxy directly, either in [proxy](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#arg-proxy) argument, or using [request:set_proxy](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-request-object.html#request-set-proxy) in [splash:on_request](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-on-request) callback a Lua script. For example, if Tor can be accessed from Splash Docker container as tor:8123, you can do a request like this:

```
http://<splash-url>:8050/render.html?url=...&proxy=socks5://tor:8123
```

Also, take a look at https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium - it setups all of this - it sets up 'tor' proxy profile, starts Tor in another Docker container, and links these containers. To access remote website using Tor in a Splash deployed via Aquarium you can just add `proxy=tor` GET argument to a request:

```
http://<splash-url>:8050/render.html?url=...&proxy=tor
```

Comment: do I have to include the `'proxy': 'tor'` part in my request, like here:
`yield SplashRequest(auction_results_url, 
                                self.parse_auction_list, 
                                endpoint='execute',
                                args = {'lua_source': self.lua_script, 'proxy': 'tor'}
                                )
`
I can't see in the logs if the requests are really going through tor

Comment: @mikhail-korobov What about (1), how to run splash and tor in same docker container or how to make tor accessible from splash docker container?

Comment: @KrishanKumarMourya it is a matter of configuring Docker. aquarium uses docker-compose to start several Docker containers at once (a few Splash containers, load balancer, tor) and connects them using "links" feature